# How to wrap blit around screen edge?

Tags: python, pygame, screen, blit

Given an image, how could one "wrap" that image around the screen?

For example, if you set the image's rect style object below the screen edge- the invisible half would blit onto the top of the screen.

```
imageRect.top=800 #Below screen edge
screen.blit(image,imageRect) #Blit on both sides of the screen
```

Is this by any ways possible (in pygame)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem when I attempted a side wrap drop and collect style game. On further inspection I found a way to achieve this feat with two images. Below is the code I used.

First create two variables `display_width` and `display_height` these are the width and height of your game window.

```
display_width = [width of window]
display_height = [height of window]
```

Next create two more variables for the 'x' position of the first and second images. Then declare the image width in pixels under the `obj_width` variable.

```
img_x = ['x' position of first image]
img2_x = ['x' position of second image, works best with same 'x' as 'img_x' above]
obj_width = [width of img]
```

Now make a image function that takes the `img_x` and `img_y`. `img_x` is a local variable and not to be confused with the other `img_x`.

```
def img(img_x,img_y):
    screen.blit([image file here], (img_x,img_y))
```

Here are the conditionals I used for the program. Feel free to copy and paste.

```
if img_x + img_width > display_width:
    img(img2_x, display_height * 0.8)
    img2_x = img_x - display_width
if img_x < 0:
    img(img2_x, display_height * 0.8)
    img2_x = img_x + display_width

if img2_x + bag_width > display_width:
    img(img_x, [where you want the image to appear, ex. display_height * 0.8])
    img_x = img2_x - display_width
if img2_x < 0:
    img(img_x, display_height * 0.8) #same as above
    img_x = img2_x + display_width
```

In this example the image moves horizontal, if you want vertical movement just change around the variables to your liking. I hope this answers your question, if something isn't working correctly or if their are any typos feel free to comment below. I know this was question was posted roughly a year ago, so sorry if its too late.

Good luck, JC

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's anything built in; just figure out where the vertical and horizontal divisions in the image are, and perform multiple blits.